# Get coordinates of "treasure" (turtles) in Maze Game that uses Python tkinter and turtle

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics, maze

I am using Python 3 to make a maze using tkinter and turtle graphics. Most of the code works, except I cannot figure out how to "destroy" the "gold" in the game. Specifically, calling `player.collision()`, it says `Question object has no attribute xcor` even though I got this from a tutorial about a turtle Python maze game. I figured it would work the same as it did in that context, but with tkinter, everything seems to change. The problem occurs under `player.collision()` and the `while` loop at the end. Those are the two sections of code that are meant to "destroy," or hide, the "gold" turtles. I have included (almost) my entire code so everyone can see what is going on.

(In addition to this question, I would like to create a way to move the player using the arrow keys rather than the buttons on the frame, but I can't figure out how.)

I have tried naming the turtle specifically rather than just "other" in the `collision()` function. I have also tried making new methods under the `Question` class to "getX" and "getY" by returning `tur3.xcor()` and `tur3.ycor()` respectively. But this did not do anything except give me another error. Like I said, this code WORKED when it was just a turtle maze, but since adding tkinter, I have had to change a whole bunch of things.

```
import turtle
import tkinter
import math

# Create window and canvas using tkinter.
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Language Labyrinth")
cv = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=600, height=600)
cv.pack()

# Create frame where button(s) will be.
frame = tkinter.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

# Create Pen class to draw the maze.
class Pen():
    def __init__(self):
        global tur
        global screen
        tur = turtle.RawTurtle(cv)
        screen = tur.getscreen()
        tur.shape("square")
        tur.color("white")
        screen.bgcolor("black")
        tur.penup()
        tur.speed(0)

# Create setup so the maze will be drawn.
    def setup(self, level):
        global tur, walls
        for y in range(len(level)):
            for x in range(len(level[y])):
                char = level[y][x]

                screenx = -288 + (x * 24)
                screeny = 288 - (y * 24)

                if char == "X":
                    tur.goto(screenx, screeny)
                    tur.stamp()

                    walls.append((screenx, screeny))

# Create player class to have a player.
class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        global tur2
        tur2 = turtle.RawTurtle(cv)
        tur2.shape("square")
        tur2.color("blue")
        tur2.penup()
        tur2.speed(0)

# Create setup to create the player on the screen.
    def setup2(self, level):
        global tur2
        for y in range(len(level)):
            for x in range(len(level[y])):
                char = level[y][x]

                screenx = -288 + (x * 24)
                screeny = 288 - (y * 24)

                if char == "P":
                    tur2.goto(screenx, screeny)

# Define a function that will allow player to move up.
    def up(self):
        global tur2, walls
        # Calculate the spot to move to.
        movetoX = tur2.xcor()
        movetoY = tur2.ycor() + 24

        # Check if the space has a wall.
        if (movetoX, movetoY) not in walls:
            tur2.goto(movetoX, movetoY)

# Define a function that will allow player to move down.
    def down(self):
        global tur2, walls
        # Calculate the spot to move to.
        movetoX = tur2.xcor()
        movetoY = tur2.ycor() - 24

        # Check if the space has a wall.
        if (movetoX, movetoY) not in walls:
            tur2.goto(movetoX, movetoY)

# Define a function that will allow player to move left.
    def left(self):
        global tur2, walls
        # Calculate the spot to move to.
        movetoX = tur2.xcor() - 24
        movetoY = tur2.ycor()

        # Check if the space has a wall.
        if (movetoX, movetoY) not in walls:
            tur2.goto(movetoX, movetoY)

# Define a function that will allow player to move right.
    def right(self):
        global tur2, walls
        # Calculate the spot to move to.
        movetoX = tur2.xcor() + 24
        movetoY = tur2.ycor()

        # Check if the space has a wall.
        if (movetoX, movetoY) not in walls:
            tur2.goto(movetoX, movetoY)

# Check if player touches the question.
    def collision(self, other):
        global tur2
        a = tur2.xcor() - other.xcor()
        b = tur2.ycor() - other.ycor()
        distance = math.sqrt((a ** 2) + (b ** 2))

        if distance < 5:
            return True
        else:
            return False

# Create Question class to create the "gold" in the game.
class Question():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        global tur3
        tur3 = turtle.RawTurtle(cv)
        tur3.shape("circle")
        tur3.color("gold")
        tur3.penup()
        tur3.speed(0)
        tur3.goto(x, y)

    # Define function that will remove gold when collided with.
    def destroy(self):
        global tur3
        tur3.goto(2000, 2000)
        tur3.hideturtle()

# Create a levels list.
levels = [""]

# Define first level.
level_1 = [
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"XP XXXXXXX          XXXXX",
"X  XXXXXXX  XXXXXX  XXXXX",
"X       XX  XXXXXX  XXXXX",
"X       XX  XXX        XX",
"XXXXXX  XX  XXX   Q    XX",
"XXXXXX  XX  XXXXXX  XXXXX",
"XXXXXX  XX    XXXX  XXXXX",
"X  XXX Q      XXXX  XXXXX",
"X  XXX  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"X         XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"X     Q          XXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXX  X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXX  X",
"XXX  XXXXXXXXXX         X",
"XXX               Q     X",
"XXX         XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXX              X",
"XX   XXXXX        Q     X",
"XX   XXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXX",
"XX    XXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXX",
"XX    Q     XXXX        X",
"XXXX                    X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
]

# Add questions list.
questions = []

# Add the level(s) to the levels list.
levels.append(level_1)

# Class instances.
pen = Pen()
player = Player()

# Wall coordinate list.
walls = []

# Define function to setup the "gold" in the game.
def setup3(level):
    for y in range(len(level)):
        for x in range(len(level[y])):
            char = level[y][x]

            screenx = -288 + (x * 24)
            screeny = 288 - (y * 24)

            if char == "Q":
                questions.append(Question(screenx, screeny))

#screen.onkeypress(player.up, "Up")
#screen.onkeypress(player.down, "Down")
#screen.onkeypress(player.left, "Left")
#screen.onkeypress(player.right, "Right")

# Creation of buttons that will allow player to move. (BIND ARROWS W/O BUTTONS??)
up = tkinter.Button(frame, text="Up", command=player.up)
up.bind("<Up>", player.up)
up.pack()
down = tkinter.Button(frame, text="Down", command=player.down)
down.bind("<Down>", player.down)
down.pack()
left = tkinter.Button(frame, text="Left", command=player.left)
left.bind("<Left>", player.left)
left.pack()
right = tkinter.Button(frame, text="Right", command=player.right)
right.bind("<Right>", player.right)
right.pack()

# Define a function for the quit button.
def quitPlaying():
    root.destroy()
    root.quit()

# Creation of quit button.
quitButton = tkinter.Button(frame, text="Quit", command=quitPlaying)
quitButton.pack()

# Game loop in regards to the gold. (Needs debugging)
while True:
    # Check for player collision with a question.
    # Iterate through the questions list.
    for question in questions:
        if player.collision(question):
            # Destroy the question.
            question.destroy()
            # Remove question from questions list.
            questions.remove(question)

    # Update screen.
    screen.update()

# Call main game loop.
tkinter.mainloop()
```

Basically, I expect that when I move over the "gold" turtles, I want them to disappear as if I've collected them.

(And for the movement, I would expect to use the arrow keys for movement instead of the buttons, but again, this is a secondary thing.)

Comment: Hello! As a rule, when opening a question, ask only one question (side questions may worth a separate question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your immediate problem is this:

```
if player.collision(question):

def collision(self, other):
    # ...
    a = tur2.xcor() - other.xcor()
```

You call `collision()` with `question` as it's second argument and the function assumes that the second argument is a turtle when it invokes `.xcor()` on it.  But it isn't a turtle, it's a *Question instance* that *contains* a turtle.

The larger problem is that your program is a complete misunderstanding of classes, instances and globals.  Consider the `pen` instance of the `Pen` class -- you create it and ignore it as it's work is done by the global `tur` you created as a side-effect!  This sort of thing recurs throughout your program.  And it's clear you don't understand the `global` keyword so I suggest your (re)read about that.

I've reworked your program below to fix many, but not all, of the problems I saw.  The classes `Pen`, `Player`, and `Question` are now subclasses of `RawTurtle`, rather than containing one.  And no globals are set via side-effect.  Your gold now disappears when you reach it and your can use the arrow keys (just click on the window first.)

```
from turtle import RawTurtle, TurtleScreen
import tkinter

# Create Pen class to draw the maze.
class Pen(RawTurtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(screen, shape='square')
        self.speed('fastest')
        self.color('white')
        self.penup()

    # Create setup so the maze will be drawn.
    def setup(self, level):
        for y in range(len(level)):
            screen_y = 288 - (y * 24)

            for x in range(len(level[y])):
                if level[y][x] == 'X':
                    screen_x = (x * 24) - 288

                    self.goto(screen_x, screen_y)
                    self.stamp()

                    walls.append((screen_x, screen_y))

# Create player class to have a player.
class Player(RawTurtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(screen, shape='square')
        self.speed('fastest')
        self.color('blue')
        self.penup()

    # Create setup to create the player on the screen.
    def setup(self, level):
        for y in range(len(level)):
            for x in range(len(level[y])):
                if level[y][x] == 'P':
                    screen_x = (x * 24) - 288
                    screen_y = 288 - (y * 24)

                    self.goto(screen_x, screen_y)

                    return

    # Define a function that will allow player to move up.
    def move_up(self):
        # Calculate the spot to move to.
        movetoX = self.xcor()
        movetoY = self.ycor() + 24

        # Check if the space has a wall.
        if (movetoX, movetoY) not in walls:
            self.goto(movetoX, movetoY)

            gold_encounter()

    # Define a function that will allow player to move down.
    def move_down(self):
        # Calculate the spot to move to.
        movetoX = self.xcor()
        movetoY = self.ycor() - 24

        # Check if the space has a wall.
        if (movetoX, movetoY) not in walls:
            self.goto(movetoX, movetoY)

            gold_encounter()

    # Define a function that will allow player to move left.
    def move_left(self):
        # Calculate the spot to move to.
        movetoX = self.xcor() - 24
        movetoY = self.ycor()

        # Check if the space has a wall.
        if (movetoX, movetoY) not in walls:
            self.goto(movetoX, movetoY)

            gold_encounter()

    # Define a function that will allow player to move right.
    def move_right(self):
        # Calculate the spot to move to.
        movetoX = self.xcor() + 24
        movetoY = self.ycor()

        # Check if the space has a wall.
        if (movetoX, movetoY) not in walls:
            self.goto(movetoX, movetoY)

            gold_encounter()

    # Check if player touches the question.
    def collision(self, other):
        return self.distance(other) < 5

# Create Question class to create the "gold" in the game.
class Question(RawTurtle):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(screen, shape='circle', visible=False)

        self.speed('fastest')
        self.color('gold')
        self.penup()
        self.goto(x, y)
        self.showturtle()

    # Define function that will remove gold when collided with.
    def destroy(self):
        self.hideturtle()

# Define function to setup the "gold" in the game.
def setup(level):
    for y in range(len(level)):
        for x in range(len(level[y])):
            char = level[y][x]

            screen_x = -288 + (x * 24)
            screen_y = 288 - (y * 24)

            if char == 'Q':
                questions.append(Question(screen_x, screen_y))

# Define a function for the quit button.
def quitPlaying():
    root.destroy()
    root.quit()

# Game loop in regards to the gold.
def gold_encounter():
    # Check for player collision with a question.
    # Iterate through the questions list.
    for question in questions:
        if player.collision(question):
            # Destroy the question.
            question.destroy()
            # Remove question from questions list.
            questions.remove(question)

# Create window and canvas using tkinter.
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Language Labyrinth")

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=600, height=600)
canvas.pack()

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
screen.bgcolor('black')

# Create frame where button(s) will be.
frame = tkinter.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

# Add questions list.
questions = []

# Wall coordinate list.
walls = []

# Create a levels list.
levels = []

# Define first level.
level_1 = [
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"XP XXXXXXX          XXXXX",
"X  XXXXXXX  XXXXXX  XXXXX",
"X       XX  XXXXXX  XXXXX",
"X       XX  XXX        XX",
"XXXXXX  XX  XXX   Q    XX",
"XXXXXX  XX  XXXXXX  XXXXX",
"XXXXXX  XX    XXXX  XXXXX",
"X  XXX Q      XXXX  XXXXX",
"X  XXX  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"X         XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"X     Q          XXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXX  X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXX  X",
"XXX  XXXXXXXXXX         X",
"XXX               Q     X",
"XXX         XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXX              X",
"XX   XXXXX        Q     X",
"XX   XXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXX",
"XX    XXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXX",
"XX    Q     XXXX        X",
"XXXX                    X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
]

# Add the level(s) to the levels list.
levels.append(level_1)

# Class instances.
pen = Pen()
pen.setup(level_1)
player = Player()
player.setup(level_1)
setup(level_1)

# Creation of quit button.
quitButton = tkinter.Button(frame, text='Quit', command=quitPlaying)
quitButton.pack()

screen.onkeypress(player.move_up, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(player.move_down, 'Down')
screen.onkeypress(player.move_left, 'Left')
screen.onkeypress(player.move_right, 'Right')

screen.listen()

# Call main game loop.
screen.mainloop()
```

You seem to get very little out of *embedding* turtle in tkinter and this might have been cleaner left a *standalone* turtle program.  And since your various `setup*()` methods/functions never got called, your posted code doesn't really do anything.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know I have a lot to learn. I'm a sophomore in college who had no experience with Python before taking this one introductory computer science course.  Globals were technically never covered in class, I just found them on example codes and tried to utilize them. And classes have always been confusing to me. So I apologize for my lack of knowledge. I did the best I could. But again, thanks for your help. I've reviewed your changes and I think I understand most of them. (: